# Removing style from dynamically?

Tags: javascript

Hi  i am having a number of style tags in the head tag in HTML5 .How to remove a particular tag from that list of style.Below is the code i need to use.I need to the style tag with height:50px or remove the style Height:50px from that tag. What should i do?

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>p:hover{color:red;background: red;}</style>
    <style>p:hover{color:yellow;height:50px}</style>'
</head>    
<body>
<p>HELLO</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want remove the 50px when mouse gets hover your link ?

Comment: My first thought is why do you have two style tags?  You only need one.  You can put all of your CSS inside one style.  Secondly, what do you want to trigger the style change?  A mouse over?  A click?

Comment: This is just a example.I need this answer for different scenario which i cant explain now?Can you help me to resolve my problem

Comment: @daguru yes i want to

Comment: please avoid to use two style tag try to set style dynamically.

Comment: If I understand you correctly then this is not the way to use CSS. Explain your problem and may be someone can come up with a proper solution.

Comment: I just answer your question with an example here : http://jsfiddle.net/M4ULF/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change background color on mouseover you can to this with http://jquery.com/
You can do the same to change the with or the height of your element by changing
`$(this).css("background-color", "red");` by ´$(this).css("height", "50px");´

Here is an example : http://jsfiddle.net/M4ULF/

**CSS**

```
#my_id{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:#999; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p id="my_id"></p>
```

**JAVASCRIPT (jQuery)**

```
$("#my_id").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
})
$("#my_id").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "#999");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at JQuery. The CSS API in Jquery allows one to add and remove css attributes to an element dynamically. http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 1):

Styles are loaded in the order they are presented to the browser. If you declare a style twice, then the second will always overwrite the first UNLESS presented with a `!important` attribute on the end.

For example:

```
p:hover {
   height: 50px;
}

p:hover {
   height: auto !important; /* this will win */
}

p:hover {
   height: 100px;
}
```

In your situation, the !important is only necessary if you have attempted to overwrite the existing style and it's just not working for you for some unindentified reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the style attribute of an element and that will override the element or class style.

Alternatively, add a class to the P tag where the class has a style. The class will override the element style.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather override CSS with the new rule after ones you've shown:

```
p:hover{height:auto}
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/oXIHIkE/1/edit).

But it's also possible to remove height property via JS. Assuming the page looks the same is as in question, the code will be:

```
document.styleSheets[1].rules[0].style.removeProperty("height")
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/AqECUyU/1/edit).

You can read about CSS DOM API [over here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration).